# How to delete empty line from txt file after replacing it

Tags: python, txt

Lets say I have a txt file that goes like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

```
a = input("text to delete from file: ")

with open('save.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read()
with open('save.txt', 'w') as file:
    new_text = text.replace(a, '')
    file.write(new_text)
```

After the user has typed `Line 2` as his input on the `a` variable, txt file goes like this:

```
Line 1
whitespace/empty line
Line 3
```

How can I delete the empty line?

Comment: Desired result `Line 1`  and `Line 3` with no blank lines in between

Comment: @Mark I generally assume that blank lines in example file contents are just to keep SO from wrapping the lines, because they don't think of putting them in code blocks.

Comment: It's not clear if `"text to delete from file"` can include text that is only a partial line. What should happen if `a` is `"in"`? Would that be three lines in the form of `"Le 1"` or would nothing be deleted?

Comment: This shows the importance of naming things correctly. “Text to delete from file” is not really accurate, as you replace text from file with empty characters. More accurate would be the question: “Text to blank from file”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the input into a list of lines. Remove the lines that match the user's input, then join them back together.

```
a = input("text to delete from file: ")

with open('save.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read().splitlines()
new_text = [line for line in text if line != a]

with open('save.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(new_text) + '\n')
```

Comment: Is the `new_text = [line for line in text if line != a]` on purpose not intended inside the first `with` or it does not matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Once you've read the file into a variable, you don't need to keep the file open, so you should close it as soon as it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the newline as well as the user's text.

```
new_text = text.replace(a + '\n', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This will save the text with no empy line to the variable final_text.

line_to_delete = "fifth line"

with open("data/test.txt") as file:
    text = file.read()
    print(text)
    text2 = text.replace(line_to_delete, "")

    text3 = [text for text in text2.splitlines() if text]
    final_text = " \n".join(text3) 
    print(final_text)
```